# Optimizing a query

Tags: apex, soql, query, governorlimits, contracts

Is there any way the below code can be simplified into a single query?:

```
List<Contract> contractsToUpdate = new List<Contract>();

        for (Contract cont: [SELECT AccountId, OwnerId, Account.OwnerId FROM Contract WHERE Account.Type != 'Wholesale partner']) {
            if (cont.OwnerId != cont.Account.OwnerId) {
                cont.OwnerId = cont.Account.OwnerId;
                contractsToUpdate.add(cont);
            }
        }
```

My approach:

```
for (Contract cont: [SELECT AccountId, OwnerId, Account.OwnerId FROM Contract WHERE Account.Type != 'Wholesale partner' AND OwnerId != Account.OwnerId]) {
                cont.OwnerId = cont.Account.OwnerId;
                contractsToUpdate.add(cont);
            }
```

But `OwnerId != Account.OwnerId` is not allowed in SOQL hence my approach is not valid

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that you are not using two queries above, but rather one query to get your "outer contracts", and then one more query per. If you have 100 "outer contracts" you'll consume your governor limit and get a `LimitsException`.

No, you can't do what you want in one query. However, you *can* add a checkbox formula that will tell you what you need to know, then query on that.

**Formula**

```
OwnerId = Account.OwnerId
```

**Query**

```
WHERE Is_Owned_By_Account_Owner__c = false
```